# laravael 9 Validation Segment with some condition

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9, laravel-validation

I am working on the online application. it has several sections. some of the sections are shown in some conditions only. some of the validation rules also apply in the dynamic section .how do i segment the validation rule based on the condition.I try following the way and it does not work for me.

```
$validatedData = $request->validate([
            'titel_id' => ['required'],
            'initials' => ['required','regex:/^[A-Za-z.]+$/'], 
            'name_denoted_by_initials' => 'required',
            'last_name' => 'required|alpha',
            'phone_no' => 'max:12',

            /********************************* */
            

        ],[
            'titel_id.required' => 'the title required',
            'initials.required' => 'the name initials required',
            'initials.regex' => 'initials only can include letters and dots',
            'name_denoted_by_initials.required' => 'the initials denoted name required',
            'last_name.required' => 'the last name required',
            'phone_no.max' => 'you entered phone number invalid',
            

        ]);

        if($vacancy->main_category_id == 46){

        $validatedData = $request->validate([
            'index_no' => 'required',
            'year' => 'required|max:'.(date('Y')),

        ],[
            'index_no.required' => 'O/l Exam number is required',
            'year.required' => 'O/l Exam year is required',

        ]);
     }
```

this only shows the without condition validation rule only. how do I manage it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`sometimes()`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#complex-conditional-validation) which helps to create ***Complex Conditional Validation***

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    # default validations
]);

$validator->sometimes('index_no', 'required', function ($vacancy) {
    return $vacancy->main_category_id === 46;
});

$validator->sometimes('year', 'required|max:'.(date('Y')), function ($vacancy) {
    return $vacancy->main_category_id === 46;
});
```

Check how to use [Manually Creating Validators](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#manually-creating-validators)

---

**Update**

Saw in the old Laravel doc. If both fields use the same validation, you can merge them.

```
$validator->sometimes(['index_no', 'year'], 'required', function ($vacancy) {
    return $vacancy->main_category_id === 46;
});
```

---

**Method 02**

Create `formRequest` and validate

```
php artisan make:request VecancyRequest
```

**In `VecancyRequest.php`**

```
class VecancyRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        if ($this->get('main_category_id') === 46) {
            $rules['index_no'] = 'required';
            $rules['year'] = 'required|max:' . (date('Y'));
        }
        $rules['titel_id'] = 'required';
        $rules['initials'] = 'required|regex:/^[A-Za-z.]+$/';
        # other validations

        return $rules;
    }

    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'index_no.required' => 'O/l Exam number is required',
            'year.required' => 'O/l Exam year is required',
            'titel_id.required' => 'the title required',
            'initials.required' => 'the name initials required',
            'initials.regex' => 'initials only can include letters and dots',
            'name_denoted_by_initials.required' => 'the initials denoted name required',
            'last_name.required' => 'the last name required',
            'phone_no.max' => 'you entered phone number invalid',
        ];
    }
}
```

**In controller**

```
public function store(VecancyRequest $request)
```

> Remove all validations from the controller. Form Request do the trick

Comment: also, you can create an array of validation rules, merge any other rules based on condition and then pass the array to the validate function.

Comment: still not working bro.only main section errors only

Comment: What no way. What is the error? It's just a validation

Comment: i mean only show main section validation massage only

Comment: @NipunSachinda check the edit. More +++Laravel way

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248532/discussion-between-nipun-sachinda-and-abdulla-nilam).

Comment: @NipunSachinda what's up